# How to link a button to the "next" page in vuejs2, when next page varies

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have a series of tabs in Vuejs as below. I want to add buttons below the content of each tab that go to the "next" and "previous" tab and are labeled with the title of the next (or previous) tab.    The problem is I don't always show all the tabs depending on certain things.

So what method could I use to show the applicable button with correct route?  I started out with hard coded buttons on each vue file pointing to the route of the next tab, but that doesn't work for me anymore since the tabs are not always the same.

```
 <template>
<div>       
        <v-tabs color="" slider-color="blue" grow="" style='box-shadow:0 0px 0 1px #ddd;'>
            <v-tab to="/customer/info" ripple=""> General Information</v-tab>
            <v-tab to="/customer/quotes" ripple="" v-if="showQuotes">Quotes</v-tab>
            <v-tab to="/customer/events" ripple="">Events</v-tab>
            <v-tab to="/customer/note" ripple="">
                <v-badge color="indigo">
                    <span slot="badge">{{notesCounter}}</span>
                    Notes
                </v-badge>
            </v-tab>
            <v-tab to="/customer/more" ripple="">More</v-tab>
        </v-tabs>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store your tabs in an array and use it to compute an array for rendering.

**Template:**

```
 <template>
   <div>       
    <v-tabs color="" slider-color="blue" grow="" style='box-shadow:0 0px 0 1px #ddd;'>
      <v-tab v-for="(tab, index) in tabsToShow"
             :to="tab.to" ripple="">{{tab.name}}</v-tab>
    </v-tabs>
    <router-view></router-view>
    <a v-if="selectedTabIndex > 0"
       :href="tabsToShow[selectedTabIndex - 1].to">
      {{tabsToShow[selectedTabIndex - 1].name}}</a>
    <a v-if="selectedTabIndex < tabsToShow.length - 1"
       :href="tabsToShow[selectedTabIndex + 1].to">
      {{tabsToShow[selectedTabIndex + 1].name}}</a>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Script:**

```
data() {
  return {
    tabs: [
      {
        to: '/customer/info',
        name: 'General Information',
        visible: true,
      },
      // other tabs
    ],
    selectedTabIndex: 0,
  }
},
computed: {
  tabsToShow() {
    return this.tabs.filter(tab => tab.visible);
  },
},
```

Then, all you have to do is somehow get an index of currently selected tab in an filtered array. For example, on click.

Comment: Thank you @Sui-Dream ! I am going to play around with this idea!